# Sysprep Automatic computer name

Tags: sysprep

I'd like to sysprep to give an automatic name to each new computer, but not fully automatic. I'd like it to be "Client1", "Client2" and so on. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: The configuration of the sysprep inf file is static, so I think cant be done (with only one conf file). BUT maybe it's as easy as configure a script just before doing the sysprep, running it (will give random name) and in the next start the script can rename it the way you want.

Comment: Is it for XP or vista / 7 ? if i remeber correclty, sysprep changed with the new versions of ms's os

Answer (score 1):

It will be significant in relation to the Operating System that you are trying to set this up on.  We have used a utility called [MySysprep](http://www.tsaysoft.com/mysysprep/) in the past and had good success with it and auto naming of computers.  We have our computers automatically named with our SysPrep configuration and the MySysprep utility such that they end up with a name of prefix-serial number or prefix-service tag.

I hope that this helps.